# SBT project compilation issues

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt

I am trying to compile my previously running project, but somehow am getting a file not found exception.

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Apps\SampleProject\project\target\config-classes\$b1d9fdc681faae2e80f2.cache (The system cannot find the file specified)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
        at sbt.Using$$anonfun$fileInputStream$1.apply(Using.scala:73)
        at sbt.Using$$anonfun$fileInputStream$1.apply(Using.scala:73)
        at sbt.Using$$anon$2.openImpl(Using.scala:65)
        at sbt.OpenFile$class.open(Using.scala:43)
        at sbt.Using$$anon$2.open(Using.scala:64)
        at sbt.Using$$anon$2.open(Using.scala:64)
        at sbt.Using.apply(Using.scala:23)
        at sbt.IO$.transfer(IO.scala:305)
        at sbt.IO$.read(IO.scala:688)
        at sbt.compiler.Eval$$anon$3.read(Eval.scala:92)
        at sbt.compiler.Eval$$anon$3.read(Eval.scala:83)
        at sbt.compiler.Eval.evalCommon(Eval.scala:149)
        at sbt.compiler.Eval.eval(Eval.scala:96)
```

Things that I have tried

```
 sbt clean
```

Manually deleting all the files from the target folder and then running the command

```
  sbt compile
```

Both of them did not work. Any pointers would be highly helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you could try deleting the target directory so that it gets regenerated

Comment: try updating the sbt version could help.

Comment: Remove both `project/project/target` and `project/target` directories, the compilation will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try deleting the `C:\Apps\SampleProject\project\target` directory itself?

I had the same issue just now and deleting that directory in its entirety solved the issue. Deleting the contents of the directory may not be enough.